# How to get errors from Passport strategy to create json response?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, bearer-token, passport.js

I'm creating an JSON API with express and I'm using Passport with the HTTP Bearer strategy for authentication.

I've added `passport.authenticate('bearer', {session: false})` as middleware. But whenever something is wrong with the session it simply responds with the body Unauthorized and status 401. The actual information is in the `WWW-Authenticate` header, in the form of a challenge, something like: 

`Bearer realm="Users", error="invalid_token", error_description="invalid token"`

And when no authentication tokens where given:

`Bearer realm="Users"`

I'd like to change the response into json which includes the error information.

As I don't have a lot of experience writing things for the backend, I've been reading through the docs and code. 
The [Bearer strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer/blob/master/lib/strategy.js) simply calls fail with `400` or a challenge string. Basically there is where my issue begins, since I don't want to write a parser for these challenge strings, why isn't this information passed as regular variables?

In [Passport's authenticate middleware](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L104-L175) this challenge is then, depending on your config, passed to callback, req.flash, the session and/or the WWW-Authenticate header. Looking through this code it tries to actually retrieve `challenge.type` and `challenge.message` first. When failure handling is not delegated to the application it checks whether the challenges are strings and if so puts them into the WWW-Authenticate header. This might be the reason the bearer strategy returns the challenge as string? 
So maybe in my case it makes sense to supply a callback, so that I can directly access these challenges? 
But then still, bearer's challenge is a string which requires parsing? 
Are people not using this bearer strategy for JSON API's?

Answer (score 0):

The default failure response in `passport` is here:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L174

However, if you provide an `authenticate` `callback` it will run this code:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L107

So the solution is to provide a callback argument to `authenticate(passport, name, options, callback)`. You can then you can intercept the authentication failures and respond to them as you please.

Note that the `res` object is not actually passed to your callback. You will have to wrap your call to `authenticate` like so to respond:

```
(req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('bearer', { /* options */ }, (err, user, challenges, statuses) => {
    if (statuses) {
      res
        .status(401)
        .json({
          challenges,
          statuses,
        })
        .end();
    } else {
       next(); // We are authenticated!
    }
  })(req, res, next);
}
```